# Modally presented UIViewController does not empty memory on close

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a problem, that caused me quite some hours/days of debugging so far.

My situation is:

- i have a viewcontroller that displays some data
- when a user clicks a button another view controller is presented modally
- after the user closes the modal controller, the memory usage does not decrease

I do not hold references (either weak or strong) for the modal view anywhere.

This is how the segue is performed:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
   SomeViewController *vc = (SomeViewController *)[nav topViewController];
   vc.dataArray = self.dataArray; // dataArray is a weak reference
}
```

And this is how i close it:

```
-(void)closeButtonClickHandler:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In my viewDidDisapear method, i set everything to nil

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.map removeAnnotations:self.myMap.annotations];
    self.map.delegate = nil;
    self.map = nil;

    self.view = nil;

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

But the controller still remains in memory. What is even worse is, that if i open it multiple times, it keeps adding to the consumed memory until eventually the OS is forced to close the application.

Any/all help is appreciated :)

Comment: In general, if you are presenting the controller from navigation controller, you should dismiss it from there only. Try with [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: are you sure it is the controller staying in memory not some objects you are using within its context? Try overriding dealloc with some logs or use instruments to get a clue which objects exactly are staying in memory.

Comment: @Apurv i've tried with that as well and it did not perform any differentl

Comment: @JonathanCichon i think you might be on to something. I checked the basic view logic and all was good... Then i found a long lost 'strong' reference to one of my elements. After I replaced it with a 'weak' one, the memory was FINALY being released :)

Answer (score 0):

I of found out that a small side view had a wrong reference set. It was 'strong', should have been 'weak'

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UISomeView * someView;
```

After that the memory was released normally and did not stack up any more

tnx @JonathanCicohons for the hint :)